# dynamic select option from ajax no space

Tags: jquery, ajax, whitespace

```
success: function(data) {

    //console.log(data);

    var country = $('#Country');
    country.empty();
    $('#Cities').empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $(country).append('<option id=' + data[i].sysid + ' value=' + data[i].name + '>' + data[i].name + '</option>');

        //console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + data[i].sysid);
        //console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + data[i].name);
    }
    //manually trigger a change event for the contry so that the change handler will get triggered
    $(country).change();

}
```

I have a select option that i populate like this using ajax. I get the data from database. My question is why does this code not include space for example the coutnry is `United States Of America` the code will only save the value as `United` the value of the country is only `United` when i save it. It will not be complete how to make it in a way that even it there is space it will still be counted in the value

Comment: What does `data` look like? maybe add a sample of that to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the value (and the ID)

`value="' + data[i].name + '">'`

resulting in

`value="United States Of America">`

Comment: Ty.. i will tick it in a while

Comment: it was a mistake on my part sorry i fixed it all is well.. i ticked it already